# Angular edit checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to edit the "Group" of some elements in a table. For that i select the elements in the table with a checkbox and after with a select i try the group that i want. The problem is that for edit when i check the button i can't send the liftsideid that i need for edit and always appears like undefined.
I simplify with and example that i put in comments.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VFWyrQORIr0TQav6UYl7?p=preview

```
<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" ng-click="updateGroup(selectedgroup, myliftsite)" ng-hide="edit"> Añadir al Grupo</button>
```

Comment: It would be better if you use `ng-model` and possibly `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjxfFZS0sPduAcBV83cX?p=preview).

Your problem is that you use `ng-model` **inside** the [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope

So your `ng-model` actually binds to the `child scope` inside the loop. If you bind to some primitive variable, JS engine will **create** a new primitive value to the child scope. So, try to bind the model to some object defined outside `ng-repeat`.